# Что за ужас сделали с главной страницей?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, дизайн

Теперь она выглядит вот так:

[image: скриншот]

Вот эти надписи - это жуть и совершенно неудобно:

[image: скриншот надписей]

Comment: Полностью согласен.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081

Comment: Это для телефонов похоже сделали https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj1Wm.jpg

Comment: С каждым обновлением дизайн на SO все хуже и хуже.

Comment: Ну простите их, видимо есть только старые телефоны для тестирования нового дизайна

Comment: Шляпа не удобная.

Comment: Вот  чёрт, а я уже привык к старой версии (хотя я здесь и недавно)...

И вообще, зачем они вообще сунулись менять дизайн, если и старый тоже был неплох? Раньше хотя бы можно было сразу прикинуть, без проблем, сколько народу посмотрело и ответило, а так сразу и не разберёшься: шрифт меньше, панели меньше... =/

Comment: @ori на телефоне так же неудобно читается. (я, похоже, вчера застал тот момент, когда поменяли - было как обычно и вдруг изменилось)

Comment: выглядит будто стили не подгрузились

Comment: А кто вообще сидит на главной?)) Она вообще кому-то нужна?))

Comment: Пустовато https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUYD5.png

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я, к примеру, только ее и использую

Comment: @avp а каков практический смысл ею пользоваться?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а какой смысл задавать вопрос, ответ на который вас все равно не интересует?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а как еще увидеть всю текущую картину? А вообще,   видимо просто привык и не вижу смысла ничего менять.

Comment: @Эникейщик почему вы так решили?

Comment: @avp общую картину чего? Не оч. понимаю. В целом увидеть активность по сайту во всех вопросах вместе взятых?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, общую картину во всех вопросах. Соответственно, общую картину *"незнания"* по всем темам IT (конечно, не надо прямо проецировать это на истинное положение дел в отрасли, но некоторые тенденции можно увидеть)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский из-за общей поставновки и формулировки вопроса

Comment: @Эникейщик вы сделали неправильный вывод

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я тоже пользуюсь только главной.

Comment: Интересный вопрос, как теперь перевести Watched, чтобы ширина левой колонки не слишком раздулась?

Comment: Мне лично, больше всего не нравится, что теперь отсутствует краткое описание вопроса под заголовком, к остальному можно привыкнуть. Но в целом да, раньше было лучше. Радует, что фильтруя вопросы "пользовательским фильтром", выводятся они в старом дизайне до сих пор.

Comment: Так выглядит UI без UX. Прямо вот академический пример, как делать не надо.

Comment: Они ещё и отслеживаемые теги ярко желтым сделали, когда оно нафиг не нужно. Подсветки и так хватает...

Comment: Был вполне нормальный UX UI, взяли и превратили в какой-то XU UI

Comment: Новый дизайн *лучше*, 170 active users не могут ошибаться :) Жесть какая-то, я сначала подумал что на телефоне глюк, потом открыл декстоп ... omg.

Comment: О боги, они это довезли до вкладки Вопросы, я уж надеялся, что хоть здесь норм останется. Жесть какая-то.

Comment: @aepot: то ли ещё будет!.. Думаю, следующий удар нанесут по редактору ответа.

Answer (score 12):

Я пытался..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выделение синим фоном и бордером делал давно под себя, приложил в коде, т.к. "дефолтная подсветка" отслеживаемых вопросов была убрана (но это не точно).

```css
.example {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(white), to(black));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, white, black);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
}

.s-post-summary__watched {
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 255, .015);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 0 0 0 #08f inset;
  box-shadow: 3px 0 0 0 #08f inset;
}

.s-post-summary--stats {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal !important;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal !important;
  -ms-flex-direction: row !important;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  -webkit-box-pack: center !important;
  -ms-flex-pack: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  -webkit-box-align: center !important;
  -ms-flex-align: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  -ms-flex-item-align: start !important;
  align-self: flex-start !important;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
  flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
  width: 150px !important;
  position: relative;
}

.s-post-summary--stats-item {
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-box-pack: center !important;
  -ms-flex-pack: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  -webkit-box-align: center !important;
  -ms-flex-align: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  min-width: calc((100% - 12px) / 3) !important;
  width: calc((100% - 12px) / 3) !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  margin-right: 6px !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
}

.s-post-summary--stats-item-number {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.425rem !important;
}

.s-post-summary--stats-item.has-bounty {
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: auto !important;
  min-width: auto !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.s-post-summary__watched .is-watched,
.s-post-summary--stats-item.has-accepted-answer>svg {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Для работы кода использую расширение **Stylish** (для [FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/stylish/), для [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=ru))

---

Поддерживаю, что решение SO ужасное, но думаю обратно они не вернут, по этому буду сидеть на "кастомном".

---

Правки по коду.
*1.1* Ломается отображение "голоса, ответ, показы" когда появляется бонус за ответ, по этому принято решение не менять их положение, т.к. нет возможности "привязаться" к конкретным элементам.

*1.2* Вернул цифрам большой размер (спасибо [@Qwertiy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11866/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9?cb=1#comment51118_11867) за подсказку)

*1.3* Ребята из SO сменили HTML счётчиков, поправил под это изменение

Comment: Спасибо! Еще бы размер чисел прежний вернуть, но видимо не судьба…

Comment: @eanmos, да, не судьба. Жаль в CSS нету `:first-word`

Comment: @De.Minov, width + first-line.

Comment: @Qwertiy, хм.. Сейчас попробую

Comment: stylish ворует данные, хватит его советовать. Используйте [Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne)

Answer (score 10):

[Скрипт от заморских коллег](https://stackapps.com/q/9293/79227), исправляющий положение.

[image: пикча]

Comment: У меня вообще не заработало. Просто ничего не изменилось после install по ссылке. Браузер перезапускал. `(Firefox 95.0 Mozilla Firefox for Linux Mint mint - 1.0)`

Comment: @avp А расширение на FF какое? У меня tampermonkey. Оно вам предложило после перехода по ссылке установить скрипт? Если зайти на страничку с вопросами и нажать на иконку расширения, там подписано, что скрипт работает?

Comment: Стооит какой-то Greasemonkey (насколько помню, ставил, чтобы русские шрифты в том же  SO улучшить). Сам скрипт Legacy Options в меню этого расширения есть. В меню options этого скрипта я добавил в User includes и User matches `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/*`. Ничего не происходит. Попробую еще раз перезапустить браузер.

Comment: Перезапустил. Поигрался с "only use this" в меню скрипта. Не работает.

Comment: @avp Попробуйте tampermonkey вместо greasemonkey (скрипт на шрифты в нем тоже работает). У меня тоже greasemonkey раньше стоял, но я почему-то заменил на этот.

Comment: Спасибо, но пожалуй, не буду. Видимо, шеф, жестко высказавшийся вчера про качество современных программеров, прав.

Answer (score 7):

Переделал себе немного внешний вид, не могу смотреть на эти ярлыки цвета жидкого стула.

Для внесения CSS правок на страницы сайта использую расширение `User CSS` для Chrome, у меня работает вполне шустро оно, иногда небольшая задержка при внесении правок правда заметна.

Стили следующие:

```css
:root {
  --color-grey: rgb(0 0 0 / 35%);
  --color-viewed-post: #f1e5bb;
}

.s-post-summary__watched {
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 0 0 var(--color-viewed-post) inset;
}

.s-post-summary--stats {
  color: var(--color-grey);
  width: auto;
  min-width: 90px;
}

.s-post-summary--stats .s-post-summary--stats-item.s-post-summary--stats-item__emphasized {
  color: var(--color-grey);
}

.post-tag.s-tag__watched {
  color: var(--theme-tag-color);
  background-color: var(--theme-tag-background-color);
  border-color: var(--theme-tag-border-color);
  padding: .4em 0.5em !important;
}

.post-tag.s-tag__watched:before {
  display: none
}

a.s-link__muted,
.s-link.s-link__muted {
  color: var(--color-grey);
}

.s-user-card.s-user-card__minimal {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  justify-items: end;
}

.s-user-card.s-user-card__minimal .s-user-card--avatar {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.s-user-card.s-user-card__minimal .s-user-card--info {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

.s-user-card.s-user-card__minimal .s-user-card--time {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.s-user-card--awards li {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.s-avatar {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.s-avatar .s-avatar--image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Было:**
[image: Было]

**Стало:**
[image: Стало]

Answer (score 5):

Выскажу непопулярное мнение (судя по ответам и количеству голосов "за"):

Ваши возмущения, господа, это просто боязнь перемен и желание остаться в состоянии равновесия? Привычный интерфейс, который использовался годами, вам кажется родным и ламповым. Возможно, меня тоже когда нибудь настигнет участь стариковского мышления сохранять "вымышленные" удобства, которые просто сформированы привычками, но в данный момент мне не понятны ваши возмущения и желания все вернуть обратно.

Я стараюсь помнить, что молодежь вокруг меня постоянно что-то меняет и их не напрягает незначительные перемены. Более того они к ним тянутся и сами их создают. Я выбираю не обращать внимание на мелочи изменения интерфейса. Я посидел, попробовал и понимаю, что глобальных перемен, которые заставляют меня страдать нет вовсе.

Я не навязываю свою точку зрения, не нравится -> протестуйте. Ну и конструктивная критика изменений - тоже хорошо.

Comment: Не во всем согласен с автором, но в целом поддержу. Слишком много шума и недовольства из-за мелких, по сути, изменений. Несколько грустно, что под вопросом теперь нет начала его текста, но оно и так, зачастую, было бесполезно. Все остальные изменения чисто на уровне "непривычно". Функционал не изменился, визуальные изменения невелики.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов начала текста вопроса на главной никогда и не было. Это на странице вопросов, оно и сейчас там.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ хм... тогда о каком "кратком  описании" говорят в комментариях под вопросом? (И да,тогда я вообще не вижу причин жалеть о смене дизайна)

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов это надо у автора коммента спрашивать. Скорее всего он просто спутал страницы.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ясно, спасибо. Я главной страницей почти не пользуюсь, так что тоже ошибся :)

Comment: Я надеюсь вы заметили, что дизайн слегка пофиксили со времени создания этого вопроса. Теперь он более терпимый, самый адские недочеты убрали и теперь изменения выглядят более терпимо. Стандартный подход, сделать всё плохо, а потом вернуть немного, и вуаля боль утихла, и скоро придёт принятие

Comment: @4per да, именно поэтому, я только сейчас и написал ответ. Посмотреть, попробовать, потестить, пофиксить - нормальная практика. Все же тут сталкиваются так или иначе с нововведениями в том числе и пользовательских интерфейсов. Не караул, же.

Comment: В общем-то изменение неболольшое (лучше стало или хуже -- это субъективно), но тут встает такой вопрос -- а зачем его вообще делать, если ничего в самом деле хорошего от него нет? Если нечем больше заняться, а ничего серьезного придумать не могут -- тогда сокращать такую команду надо

Comment: @Dmitry "Посмотреть, попробовать, потестить, пофиксить - нормальная практика". Верно. Только в этом случае эта практика не применялась. Как и в предыдущем, когда изменили дизайн страницы пользователя.

Comment: @Эникейщик смена страницы пользователя для меня вообще не вызвала никакой реакции, кроме: "О, чего-то новенькое! Дай-ка посмотрю". Да и _ruSO_ не в топе, поэтому: "Что нас спрашивать?". Хотя тут я не знаю методов взаимодействий

Comment: При чем тут вообще руСО? Здесь под вопросом во втором комментарии ссылка на общую мету. Сходите почитайте.

Comment: @Эникейщик при том, что я вообще не в курсе: Хоть чье то мнение спрашивали, вообще?  Или это инициатива и реализация ограниченной кучки людей, которым и дела нет до SO. Они им не пользуются

Comment: Немного запоздал :) Но просто скажу как "молодой" тут, мне новый дизайн больше нравится чем старый (смотрел на сайте https://web.archive.org) :)